How can change icon name in flutter of macos?
I can't just change icon name.
and I can change display name, product name in Korean.
I edited 'Icon Name' in info.plist in Xcode.
Writed in flutter
CFBundleIconName
blabla
Localization in Xcode
"CFBundleIconName" = "blabla";

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
